# Angular 1/Ui-router - Pass data from the state to controller

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

Here is my state :

```
.state({
  name: 'contact.detail.read.step.overlay',
  url: '',
  abstract: true,
  data: {
    skipFooter: true,
    cancelState: 'contact.detail.read'
  },
  views: {
    'overlay@agent': {
      component: 'overlayContent'
    }
  }
})
```

I want to run a method in this state that retrieves the name of the contact (`contactName`) and that it is recognized in the controller `overlayContent`

normally I can access contact name in the `overlayContent` controller if I add it to the bindings with :

```
  bindings: {
    contactName: '<'
  }
```

but I'm looking for a solution that does it without changing the bindings from the state, by adding it for example in the parameter data :

```
  data: {
    name: contactName,
    skipFooter: true,
    cancelState: 'contact.detail.read'
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve contactName:

```
.state({
  name: 'contact.detail.read.step.overlay',
  url: '',
  abstract: true,
  data: {
    skipFooter: true,
    cancelState: 'contact.detail.read'
  },
  views: {
    'overlay@agent': {
      component: 'overlayContent'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    contactName: () => {
      return 'what ever contactName should be';
    }
  }
})
```